# 23andMe DNA Test is reliable?

Tags: genetics, brands, dna, genetic-predisposition

Does the 23andMe DNA Test is reliable and worth to get ? Or there is nothing like the actual physical dna tests at laboratories.

Does 23andMe DNA Test provide the exact information provided by laboratories or it is a waste of time and money ?

P.S. I am not promoting for this product at all, the only thing is that DNA test are so expensive, how can a simple small machine can do that hard work instead of laboratories. So, I asked the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would like to start by saying that 23andMe performs its genetic test in CLIA certified laboratory. Processes like DNA extraction, purification, measurement can only be done under laboratory conditions.

Second, 23andMe provides you with ancestry and health information and also allows you to download your raw data. Your raw data information is txt or zip file that contains information on your polymorphism, chromosome position etc. There are third party tools who interpret this information for you to give you helpful lifestyle insights. There are around 650,000 gene markers in your 23andMe raw data file. So the information that can be dug out is enormous. For more information on such tools please refer to this [article](https://www.xcode.life/23andme-raw-data/23andme-raw-data-analysis-interpretation)